# working in app billing android application,change package name

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have working android project integrated with in app purchase.
now I created new application with different package name, added in app product with same sku in console.
now in android studio updated licence key with new app from console. Changed package name.
from all I understand it should work.
But I am not able to get sku detail on listner.

But the tab-listener is not giving detail of any sku.

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
     } 
        else { 

        //  now here inventory does not skus information

     } 
}
```

Comment: Have you published this new application apk to alpha/ beta group?

Comment: yaa,published and now it works.pity i thought,saving in draft will work.    and thank you!

Comment: great! added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish your apk (alpha/ beta group) to make it work.